# VMWare Setting WLAN adapter as WLAN not LAN

Tags: vmware-workstation

I try to use Backtrack inside my VMware workstation. I got one build in LAN adapter and one build in WLAN adapter on my host computer.

Inside backtrack or any other operative system, i find my WLAN adapter and i can use it. Problem is that it is showed as a LAN adapter.

Is there any way to say to VMware that it is a WLAN adapter and not a LAN adapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default VMware does not expose your actual network cards to the guests.

- The host (which is running your hypervisor) will have access to the real hardware.
- The guest (in your case backtrack running inside VMware) gets access to emulated hardware. In this case a faked regular LAN card. This would happen even if your host had no wired network and only wireless.

The only exception to this is if you you pass-though devices. Usually this requires a system with AMD-Vi or Intel VT-d. Then the raw hardware device will be used solely by the VM.  (Read: your host no longer will have access to it).